# 3g modem after playing with ap-hotspot

Tags: networking, wireless, connection, 3g

I got some problems with ap-hotspot and earlier installation of hosapd. Software were removed and now I got some missed option in the network panel - see picture. How to make Disconnect (Rozłącz) to work again - at this moment is unable to click - it is not active during 3g connection.

[image: screenshot]

Working ok 12.04 lts.

Just noticed that it is really troublesome when I try to use WIFI (it is only for printing - no internet) - I cant connect to internet (even if 3g connection works) because it is unable to disconnect WIFI :) Help please!!!! –

Comment: You can [edit] your question, if you have something relevant to add. It's easier to find all the info in one place than scattered throughout the comments. :-]

Comment: Can you have a look [over here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and download and execute the wireless script and post the results to http://paste.ubuntu.com and post back the link in your question?